# Finding a value in nested array then returning a value from the upper scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, filtering

What I am trying to achieve is:

1. Find if the text object within array is empty.
2. If criteria from no1 is matched, then return id value that sits in the top level of that object.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-swirles-gb6ct?file=/src/App.js:410-412
In the code sandbox's example I have added two objects, with empty text strings and in that case I would expect to get an array of strings back (result = ['662e4120', '782h7a9x'])

I am able to find empty values, however I am not sure how to return object from the upper scope.

If you can't access the codeSandbox, snippet is attached just below:

```
const array = [
{
  id: "5548d3c2",
  state: {
    properties: [
      {
        text: "text",
        key: "fs5a"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  id: "662e4120",
  state: {
    properties: [
      {
        text: "",
        key: "m03n"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  id: "782h7a9x",
  state: {
    properties: [
      {
        text: "",
        key: "y5x1"
      }
    ]
  }
}];

  const findItem = () => {
    return array
      .map((item) => item.state)
      .map((item) => item.properties)
      .flat()
      .filter((item) => item.text === "");
  };
```

Comment: " however I am not sure how to return object from the upper scope" what do you mean by that? What result are you getting, which are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And please embed the code directyl here in a snippet

Comment: hey Corrl, thanks for getting back. At this moment i am ony able to find and return objects from 'properties' that have contain empty text string. What I would like to get instead is ID's from upper scope, which in that case would be '782h7a9x' and '662e4120'

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: hey Corrl, thanks for getting back. Sure it does, works like a charm. Thanks for sharing knowledge with me!

Comment: happy to have helped! If you find an answer useful you can tell that by clicking on the arrow pointing up  on the left side of the answer (not just inside your questions but everywhere. But you need a certain amount of reputation points for beeing able to vote like that I think). If an answer solved your problem, then mark it as 'solved' by clicking on the checkmark on the left side (should work already, no reputation point restriction)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-mcnulty-2fwh4

```
export default function App() {
  const array = [
    {
      id: "5548d3c2",
      state: {
        properties: [
          {
            text: "text",
            key: "fs5a"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      id: "662e4120",
      state: {
        properties: [
          {
            text: "",
            key: "m03n"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      id: "782h7a9x",
      state: {
        properties: [
          {
            text: "",
            key: "y5x1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ];

  const findItem = () => {
    return array.filter(obj=>obj.state.properties[0].text==="").map(obj=>obj.id)
  };

  console.log(findItem());

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

Here, we are filtering on the original array based on a predicate which is `obj=>obj.state.properties[0].text===""`. This basically get all the elements of the array which satisfy this predicate function. After this we are just applying map over the result to get the ids of the array elements satisfying this predicate function.

Comment: It would be more educational for readers if you explained the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get an array with the ids of the objects with no text you have to change the order or your iterations.

1. .filter() the array for the elements with empty text fields.
2. .map() the remaining elements to the values you are aiming for

When mapping or filtering you can't just go one but as many levels deep as you like. Since 'properties' holds an array and you want the first element, you can access that with the index array[0] (with that the flat() you did is superfluous)

```js
  const findItem = () => {
    return array
      .filter(item => item.state.properties[0].text === "")   // (2) [{…}, {…}] the original items with no text
      .map(item => item.id)  // ['662e4120', '782h7a9x']
  };
```

(code might be as well embedded as a snippet, which can be run directly)

```js
const array = [
{
  id: "5548d3c2",
  state: {
    properties: [
      {
        text: "text",
        key: "fs5a"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  id: "662e4120",
  state: {
    properties: [
      {
        text: "",
        key: "m03n"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  id: "782h7a9x",
  state: {
    properties: [
      {
        text: "",
        key: "y5x1"
      }
    ]
  }
}];

  const findItem = () => {
    return array
      .filter(item => item.state.properties[0].text === "")   // (2) [{…}, {…}] the original items with no text
      .map(item => item.id)  // ['662e4120', '782h7a9x']
  };

console.log(findItem())
```